# How to inject $filter service into custom directive in component-based AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, filter, dependency-injection, angularjs-directive, html-input

I'm currently developing custom directive, which will create mask for input element.
Whole app is coded in component-based style, so every single component, directive and filter is written like that.
I need to inject $filter service into this directive, because somewhere in the middle of it I'll need to format strings using already made filters.
Unfortunately, my way of injecting the $filter doesn't work and I keep getting error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module foo due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.common due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module inputMaskModule due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $filter due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '$filter' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=%24filter

But the case is, before I've tried to inject the filter, this directive loaded and example code inside was executed without problems.

Here's the code of directive.

inputMask.js, which is for registering the directive code:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import InputMask from './inputMask.directive';

const inputMaskModule = angular.module('inputMaskModule', [])
  .directive('inputMask', () => new InputMask());

export default inputMaskModule;
```

and inputMask.directive.js which contain directive code:

```
export default class inputMask {
  constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.require = ['ngModel'];
  }

  link($scope, $element, attrs, ngModel) {
    console.log('scope:', $scope, 'element:', $element, 'attrs:', attrs, 'ngModel:', ngModel);

    const ngModelController = ngModel[0];
    // some more code
    $element.bind('focus', focusInput);
    $element.bind('blur', blurInput);
  }
}
```

I've tried to inject $filter like that:

```
const inputMaskModule = angular.module('inputMaskModule', ['$filter'])
  .directive('inputMask', ($filter) => new InputMask($filter));
```

and

```
constructor($filter) {
    this.$filter = $filter;
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.require = ['ngModel'];
  }
```

and later I'm planning to execute $filter code using this.$filter('someFilter')(someVar) to filter someVar.

But, the above injections cause error I've posted at the start of question.
Really don't know how to inject service, without redesigning whole directive - which isn't the solution I'd prefer.

Thanks for eventual help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include `$filter` as a module dependency (anyway it throws an error).
This is the correct way to inject `$filter` into your class:

```
export default class inputMask {
  constructor($filter) {
    this.$filter = $filter;
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.require = ['ngModel'];
  }

  link($scope, $element, attrs, ngModel) {
    ...
  }
}
inputMask.$inject = ["$filter"];
```

Or, if you are planning on using the `$filter` service in a controller:

```
export default class inputMask {
  constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.require = ['ngModel'];
    this.controller = 'MyController';
  }

  link($scope, $element, attrs, ngModel) {
    ...
  }
}

/*MyController.js*/
export default class MyController {
  constructor($filter) {
    this.$filter = $filter;
  }
  $onInit() {
    console.log(this.$filter('someFilter')(someVar));
  }
}
MyController.$inject = ["$filter"];

/*Be sure to register the controller*/
const inputMaskModule = angular.module('inputMaskModule')
  .controller('MyController', MyController);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using classes to define directives, inject dependencies using [`$inject` Property Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation):

```
class myDirective {
  constructor ($filter) {
    this.require= {ngModel: "ngModel"};
    this.$filter = $filter;
  }
  link (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    console.log(scope);
    console.log(ctrl);
    var ngModelController = ctrl.ngModel;
    console.log("$filter=",this.$filter);
  }
}
myDirective.$inject=["$filter"];

angular.module("app",[])
.directive("myDirective",myDirective)
```

The $compile service instantiates directives that are classes with the `new` operator and dependencies defined by the `$inject` property of the class.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/tTfTqTnWAyvvRgEaOxYI?p=preview)

Comment: Demo not working. Anyway, I've changed my code to [THAT](https://plnkr.co/edit/7cGIMshSQrFV7RvUcaFF?p=preview) and now I get such error: **Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object**. I don't get it, what's wrong...

Comment: Fixed link to DEMO